# How to call curl request to fetch data through design document?

Tags: curl, couchdb

My design document is something like this..

```
{
  "_id": "_design/dataFilter",
  "_rev": "1-29032a3479f5bfb016ea4e2f5e8afae3",
  "filters": {
    "getUser": "function (doc, req) { return (req.query.type == doc.type && req.query.id == doc._id) }",
    "getCustomer": "function (doc, req) { return (req.query.type == doc.type && req.query.id == doc.user) }",
    "getOrders": "function (doc, req) { return (req.query.type == doc.type && req.query.id == doc.user) }",
    "getCloths": "function (doc, req) { return (req.query.id == doc._id) }",
    "getDevices": "function (doc, req) { return (req.query.type == doc.type && req.query.id == doc._id) }"
  }
}
```

This is how I am trying to fetch the records from couchdb.

```
curl -X GET http://example.com/database?filter=dataFilter/getCustomer -d '{"query_params":{"id":"jayesh","type":"user"}}'
```

How can we fetch records from the couchdb with the help of design document?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the documentation of couchdb, filters can only be used for the `_changes` feed:
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#filter-functions

What you can do, is using views with map/reduce functions:
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#view-functions

You just have to `emit` all documents that match the filter. The key and the value of the `emit`-function can be used as you want.

In your example, the design-doc would look like this:

This would look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/dataFilter",
  "_rev": "1-29032a3479f5bfb016ea4e2f5e8afae3",
  "views": {
    "getUser": {
      "map": "function(doc) { if (req.query.type == doc.type && req.query.id == doc._id) { emit(doc._id, "something") } }"
    },

...

  }
}
```

After the view has been computed (what could take some time on big databases) you can fetch the results with:

`GET DB/_design/dataFilter/_view/getUser`

Comment: Yeah, I did try to play around with filtering views, but did not have any success. So I assume filters works only with _changes view. From couchdb docs  "Filter functions mostly act like Show Functions and List Functions: they format, or filter the changes feed."  I gues for dinamic lookups you shoud use _find .